# Do Usernames Hang Around for a While After Refreshing a Sandbox?

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh

Do usernames hang around for a while after refreshing a sandbox?

I refreshed an existing sandbox from production and then attempted to update users to activate them and reset their passwords. When trying to save the changes I got a Duplicate Username error:

[image]

Later in the day I attempted the same changes and it worked without error. This has me wondering if the usernames from the old sandbox were hanging around for a while?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There's a [help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318796&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) for this very situation and you guessed right.

It's either because:

1. Previous sandbox not properly deleted
2. Username replication delays

[image]